# Slide two items for two categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a possibility that for two categories (like in image), the latest item for two categories to be next or preview? Usually, in case with one category I have used Slick slider.

[image]

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="cat1">
  <div class="items></div>
  <div class="items></div>
  <div class="items></div>
  <div class="items></div>
</div>
<div id="cat2">
  <div class="items></div>
  <div class="items></div>
  <div class="items></div>
  <div class="items></div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.cat1').slick({
dots: true,
infinite: true,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 1,
centerMode: true,
variableWidth: true
});
```

The problem is that in this case, show only items from category one.

Comment: can you explain more about your question?

Comment: Your question is unclear, and the code provided isn't sufficient. Please provid the CSS or potential JavaScript you are using.

Comment: Yes, I have many items from two categories, and I want to slide items with bullets. Means that if i click one bullet, should be displayed items for each category (base on image). I hope that I'm clear :)